# how to mange dependent docker services

Tags: docker, chef-solo

I have two dockers one containing a Cassandra server and one containing a jetty server which has my application.

both dockers use chef-solo for configuration and for running tasks after the jetty and the Cassandra start.

in the Cassandra docker, we run the keyspace creation after the server has started.
and in the jetty, we preload data into the system after the server started.

the problem is that I need to know when the Cassandra docker has completed its initialization before I can start the jetty because in order to preload the data I need a connection to thew Cassandra.

my question is how can this be achieved?

- is there a docker commend that can notify the system my docker is ready?
- is there a way to check the chef if it completed its initialization?
- perhaps I need another approach?

suggestions will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no native way to do this in Docker - and the reasoning for that is because it's not how containers should be used. Your image **is** your application; and provisioning should not be happening upon coming online.

What you should do here is add your Chef scripts into a `Dockerfile` and build your image from it; that way you're ready to go when you run the application.

However if you'd like to control start-up order; you wait for the container to be **running** before starting another; but it will not wait until it is "ready". Further reading on this can be found [here.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Good luck!